# How to specify the execution order of Specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, specs2

My tests are run sequential with the option `parallelExecution in Test := false`.

It seems the execution order of the tests is not necessarily the order of the tests within my class file. Is this observation correct and if yes, is there a way to specify the execution order?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 levels of parallelization. The first one is to execute classes in parallel when using sbt. This can be deactivated with the sbt setting you mention. The second one is to execute examples in parallel inside specs2.

You can run specs2 examples sequentially by adding the `sequential` argument at the beginning of your specification:

```
class MySpec extends mutable.Specification {
  sequential
  ...
}
class MySpec extends Specification { def is = sequential ^ """
   ...
  """
}
```

or add it to your sbt build file:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "sequential")
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. When adding sequential within the test class, will the execution order of tests of this class be kept or can the order be arbritrary?

Comment: The execution order will be the order in which they are declared in the class.